# Create, lock and unlock a directory in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, process, locking

I am developing in Linux environment and run some test scripts concurrently.
Each test script will save temporary results to a its own directory. By temporary, it means if the test is run again, it will overwrite/modify previous results instead of creating new files. This is for the sake of space, otherwise I need to schedule a new job to delete files regularly.

What I want to do in a shell script is: given a path for example `A/B/C`.

1. Check if directory `A` exists, if not, create directory A
2. Check if directory `A/B` exists, if not, create directory B under A
3. Check if directory `A/B/C` exists, if not, create directory C under B, and create a lock inside C.
4. Grab/wait the lock in C. Run tests and save results to C. Release the lock in C.

Please note:

- There are multiple users running tests on the same box. To hack the permissions, I run `chmod 666 * >/dev/dnull 2>/dev>null` at the end of each test, is there a better way to change permission to 666 when I create directories?
- Tests are written in python script and is likely to crash. Be sure to avoid deadlock.
- The path can be arbitrary, `A/B1/B2/..../Bn/C`, I only want to lock the innermost directory `C`.

Thank you!

Comment: You can do steps 1-3 in one command: `mkdir -p A/B/C`

Comment: Thanks! How can I set the default permission mode as 666 for all files in dir C?

Comment: You can't do that. Permission modes are set by the application that creates files, modified by the umask of the process.